# Difficulties achieving Celluloid benchmarks in JRuby

Tags: ruby, concurrency, jvm, actor, celluloid

I'm seeing some concurrency problems in a library I'm using that implements Celluloid actors. Out of curiosity, I ran [the benchmarking script](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/blob/master/benchmarks/actor.rb) in Celluloid with a couple different interpreters.

*Ruby 1.9.3*

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
               spawn       387 i/100ms
               calls       757 i/100ms
         async calls       431 i/100ms
            messages      3063 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
               spawn     3957.4 (±3.9%) i/s -      20124 in   5.093148s
               calls     8054.8 (±5.8%) i/s -      40878 in   5.092786s
         async calls    15709.4 (±11.0%) i/s -      77580 in   5.008169s
            messages   497844.7 (±16.0%) i/s -    2383014 in   4.989021s
```

*Ruby 2.1.1*

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
               spawn       359 i/100ms
               calls       749 i/100ms
         async calls       383 i/100ms
            messages      3579 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
               spawn     3823.2 (±8.1%) i/s -      19027 in   5.011383s
               calls     8205.4 (±7.3%) i/s -      41195 in   5.049513s
         async calls    14086.1 (±8.7%) i/s -      70089 in   5.016073s
            messages   766163.5 (±19.8%) i/s -    3510999 in   4.993806s
```

*JRuby 1.7.11 using JIT*

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
               spawn        75 i/100ms
               calls       294 i/100ms
         async calls       154 i/100ms
            messages      4548 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
               spawn     2521.8 (±24.3%) i/s -      11625 in   4.999000s
               calls     8207.7 (±25.3%) i/s -      37632 in   5.049000s
         async calls     9001.3 (±30.2%) i/s -      36652 in   4.971000s
            messages   334366.4 (±14.7%) i/s -    1619088 in   4.999000s
```

*JRuby 1.7.11 using AOT*

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
               spawn        88 i/100ms
               calls       324 i/100ms
         async calls       126 i/100ms
            messages      2576 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
               spawn     2198.8 (±25.5%) i/s -       9416 in   5.004000s
               calls     6188.9 (±21.5%) i/s -      29160 in   5.014000s
         async calls     6906.6 (±26.3%) i/s -      29862 in   4.996000s
            messages   198558.0 (±20.3%) i/s -     922208 in   4.995000s
```

If I am reading this correctly, the 1.9 and 2.1 interpreters are spawning more actors than when run in JRuby. I would have expected JRuby to spawn more actors and to run faster than either of the C interpreters - but that does not seem to be the case.

Is there something missing in the way I'm running the benchmarks, or is there some difficulty in Celluloid in launching a large number of actors?

**EDIT** I originally used the wrong settings to compile AOT. The numbers now appear even lower for AOT - albeit I did not specify any other options besides compilation.